# string comparison fails c++

Tags: c++, pointers, stdstring

I don't really know what's going on in here, but when I'm running my code I get some wild error while trying to compare two strings.

```
bool remove_entry(addlist& list, std::string fname, std::string lname){
    bool more = true;
    bool failed = false;
    contact* traversal_ptr = entry;
    contact* trailer = entry;

    while (more && !failed){
        if (traversal_ptr = NULL){
            failed = true;
        }
        else if (traversal_ptr->last_name != lname || traversal_ptr->first_name != fname){
            trailer = traversal_ptr;
            traversal_ptr = traversal_ptr->next;
        }
        else {
            trailer->next = traversal_ptr->next;
            delete traversal_ptr;
        }
    }
    return failed;
}
```

I get a failure in the return line of the following block of xstring:

```
    int compare(const _Myt& _Right) const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // compare [0, _Mysize) with _Right
    return (compare(0, this->_Mysize, _Right._Myptr(), _Right.size()));
    }
```

I don't know why this is happening. I know everything being put in is a string. It doesn't even raise an exception, so I'm not sure what to do. It seems like it might be some little thing I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: set a breakpoint, debug

Comment: I did set a breakpoint. That xstring block is how far I got, and I'm pretty new to coding, and I'm not quite sure how to do anymore than see where the code fails to execute.

Comment: check the call stack

Comment: Try changing "traversal_ptr = NULL" to "traversal_ptr == NULL" as you are setting it to NULL instead of comparing to NULL.

Comment: That worked! Thank you man!

Comment: @billyreynolds With what error? That's important information.

Comment: @billyreynolds he is probably trying to access next on null ptr, what else could be the problem

Comment: Made an edit, after that change it worked just fine. I really have to start paying more attention to those comparison operators.

Comment: @billyreynolds, "Made an edit" - what edit? Something other than changing = to ==?

Comment: else block didn't include 'more = false'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if (traversal_ptr = NULL){
```

Should be

```
    if (traversal_ptr == nullptr){
```

Also, as you noted in your comment, you needed to add `more = false` to the else block, to terminate the loop.